# JPA @NamedQuery with two tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

I am new to jpa, I'm trying to convert this mysql query to jpa

```
 SELECT 
`restaurants`.`name` AS `restaurant_name`,
`menus_items`.`id` AS `dish_id`,
        `menus_items`.`name` AS `name`,
        `menus_items`.`price` AS `price`,
        `menus_items`.`description` AS `description`,
        `menus_items`.`image` AS `image`,
        `menus_items`.`tags` AS `tags`        
    FROM restaurants
    JOIN `menus_items` ON (`restaurants`.`id` = `menus_items`.`restaurant_id`)
    WHERE (6371 * acos( cos( radians(@lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(@lng) ) + sin( radians(@lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )  < 64
```

so far I have this:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "MenusItems.findByLatLong", query = "SELECT " +
"res.name AS restaurant_name, m.id AS dish_id, m.name AS name, m.price AS price, m.description AS description," +
"m.image AS image, m.tags AS tags FROM Restaurants res JOIN MenusItems m ON (r.id = m.restaurant_id)" +
"WHERE (6371 * acos( cos( radians(:lat) ) * cos( radians( r.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( r.longitude ) - radians(:lng) ) + sin( radians(:lat) ) * sin( radians( r.latitude ) ) ) )   < 64")
```

And i get the following errors:

```
[232, 381] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
[198, 313] The left side if the subtraction is not a valid arithmetic expression.
[224, 387] The left and right expressions type must be of the same type.
```

and plenty of errors like

```
The identification variable 'cos' is not defined in the FROM clause
The identification variable 'acos' is not defined in the FROM clause
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You cant use cos / sin directly with jpa. It depends on your jpa provider how you can use it. But you can use NamedNativeQuery -  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html for your sql code for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JPA in wrong way.
You should read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence)

Especially the relation chapter.
Then you will know that you should not use this kind of queries.
Try to correctly define all entities and relations in JPA way, you'll see everything will work automatically.